# Identify which UIPopover controller has been dismissed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

I have several `UIPopover`s in my app that contain `UITableView`s.  All send the message `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` when they are dismissed.  When a particular popover is dismissed, I want to take all of the user's selections and move them to a `UITextView`.

I can't do this unless I know which popover is being dismissed.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

```
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 416)];  //  was 216
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300.0, 416.0);

    //  define UITableView
    tvServices = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tvServices.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 416);
    tvServices.tag = 1201;

    tvServices.delegate = self;
    tvServices.dataSource = self;

    //  add it to the popover
    [popoverView addSubview:tvServices];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    popoverController.delegate = (id)self;
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 416) animated:NO];

    //  show it next to services textbox
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:soServices.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can check dismissed UIPopover in the delegate's method `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` then you can check by isKindOfClass: or equate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` delegate method tells you which popover is being dismissed. From there you can look at the popover's `contentViewController` as needed.

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    UITableViewController *controller = (UITableViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;

    UITableView *tableView = controller.tableView;
}
```

This should point you in the right directory. But you shouldn't need access to the table view. You be accessing the data from the view controller, not the table view.

Comment: Hi maddy... I dont' see anything that would identify the controller when using **contentViewController**... what did you have in mind?

Comment: You can check the class of the content view controller or you could set a tag on the view controller's view. If you have common processing then a better approach would be to define a protocol that all of these view controller conform to. Then you can use the protocol methods to interrogate the view controllers.

Comment: I need to get inside of the controller to see which UITableView is there... but of course, there is nothing that I'm aware of that will tell me when the UITableView disappears when in a UIPopover.

Comment: close - crashes on second line... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7eacfd0'

Comment: Then you don't have a `UITableViewController` in the popover. The code was a hint to point you in the right direction based on your comments. It's far from complete or even ideal code.

Comment: No, there is no controller, only a tableView, as I indicated in my question originally.  Thanks anyway for the help.  (btw, I have never seen an instance where a UIPopover contains a UITableView controller; all of the examples on SO and Google just have the UITableView.)

Comment: Huh? You must put a view controller in a popover controller. You can't just stick a view in it.

Comment: @spokane-dude, rmaddy is right. if you would just pass a view, it must crash.

Comment: @spokane-dude Your last comment should be added to your question, not my answer (I didn't downvote).

Comment: rmaddy:  I found a solution:
      UITableView *tableView = controller.title;
Then all I have to do is check the title... I think this will do it... btw, are you _the_ rick maddy? :D

Comment: @spokane-dude I don't think relaying on NSString title is a good idea. Better option is tag.

Comment: UITableViewControllers don't have tags... I agree with you, however; I would much rather use tags... :D

Comment: @spokane-dude - `controller.title` returns an `NSString`, not a `UITableView`. Personally, I think "vikingosegundo" has the right idea. Use a delegate pattern instead of what you are trying to do. BTW - I am *a* rick maddy, I don't know which of us you consider *the* rick maddy.

Comment: lol... I think you are _the_ Rick Maddy... I see your name all over the place with regard to articles and apps... good job! :D
BTW, I changed the controller.title code; saw the error in my ways! :D

Comment: @spokane-dude but you have `UITableView`, not an `UITableViewController` there :)

Comment: Wojtek: code has changed... it's now: 
    UITableViewController *controller = (UITableViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
    NSString *title = controller.title;

and I gave it a title and it works like a champ!  thanks for your comments and suggestions.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way around:

The controllers you present should use delegation to inform the controller that started the presentation.

In the popover controllers on you send a message to the delegate (the presenting controller) to inform it about selection/deselection.

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "QuestionGroupViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <QuestionGroupViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)presentQuestionnaire:(id)sender {

    NSArray *q = @[@{@"question" : @"what cities would you like to visit?" , @"answers": @[@"Paris", @"barcelona", @"Istanbul"]}];

        QuestionGroupViewController *qvc = [QuestionGroupViewController new];
        qvc.delegate = self;
        qvc.questions = q;
        [self presentViewController:qvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

-(void)selectedAnswer:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *)question
{
    NSLog(@"selectedt\t\t%@: %@", question, answer);
}
-(void)deSelectedAnswer:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *)question
{
    NSLog(@"deselectedt\t\t%@: %@", question, answer);
}
@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    
@protocol QuestionGroupViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
-(void) selectedAnswer:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *) question;
-(void) deSelectedAnswer:(NSString *)answer forQuestion:(NSString *) question;

@end

@interface QuestionGroupViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *questions;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<QuestionGroupViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

---

```
#import "QuestionGroupViewController.h"


@interface QuestionGroupViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedCells;

@end


@implementation QuestionGroupViewController {

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.selectedCells = [NSMutableArray array];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.questions count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.questions[section][@"answers"] count] +1 ;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.questions[section][@"question"];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    }
    if (indexPath.row == [self.questions[indexPath.section][@"answers"] count]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"done";
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section][@"answers"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == [self.questions[indexPath.section][@"answers"] count]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        return;
    }

    NSString *answer = self.questions[indexPath.section][@"answers"][indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]){
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.delegate deSelectedAnswer: answer forQuestion:self.questions[indexPath.section][@"question"]];

    } else {
        [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.delegate selectedAnswer: answer forQuestion:self.questions[indexPath.section][@"question"]];

    }

}

-(BOOL)isRowSelectedOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) ? YES : NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)[popoverController.contentViewController.view viewWithTag:1201];
    if (tableView != nil) {
        // here you know that this UIPopover has tvServices as you set its tag to 1201
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting the popovers from your code, then you should have a reference to them. When the popover delegate call is received, all you have to do is check which instance is being dismissed. Sounds simple to me, unless I missed something.